# Linking to files

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

This:

[Illustrator: transparent shapes used as highlights are visible](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104953/illustrator-transparent-shapes-used-as-highlights-are-visible)

Is a bad precedent to set..

While I fully understand the desire to be helpful, I think it's a slippery slope to allow questions to link to files. (I'm aware the link was edited in later by a more senior member and not originally part of the question)

Sure we *assume* most users would use that ability well, but not everyone will be as nice. The link provides as pseudo endorsement from this site, if not Stack Exchange directly.

Rest assured at some point someone *will* link to a virus, bad file, or for other nefarious reasons.

In addition... it positions this site *directly* in the "troubleshoot my file" direction of questioning as opposed to "how do you do this in..".

Thoughts?

Comment: Just a passer-by... I have seen similar meta posts with different approaches on different SE sites. Just want to share: [Policy for linking to blend files](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/166) on [Blender.SE], and [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428) on [SO].